# HTML Grid view and List View

Tags: javascript, html, listview, gridview

So I want my contents to change its appearance depending on what button i click (grid view and list view) ..
I did some research and most of the stuff can be done using jquery. But i want to use only javascript.
My questions are:
what elements should i use? I am currently patterning (if this is even a real word) my app by using semantic ui.

I found this snippet here in stackoverflow http://jsfiddle.net/LJf9p/794/
but I can't seem to make it run, i mean it runs but it doesnt change appearance depending on button click if i put on html, do i have to add some more stuff? it works on the fiddle but not when i run it on my local browser. thanks

```
$('button').click(function(e) {
if ($(this).hasClass('grid')) {
    $('#container ul').removeClass('list').addClass('grid');
}
else if($(this).hasClass('list')) {
    $('#container ul').removeClass('grid').addClass('list');
}
 });
```

Comment: why don't you use buttons with unique ids?

Comment: how do i call this javascript code using my button? thanks. It works on that fiddle someoen posted but when i copy it to my notepad++ then run on browser it doesnt work.. The style works tho just not the actions

Comment: @Super oh i made it work now. i just gave the buttons an onclick method, gave the ul a unique id then changed its class using document.getElementById().classname .. If ever anyone needs. Thanks still tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please add

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js
 and
$( document ).ready(function() {  });

it works

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function(e) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('grid')) {
            $('#container ul').removeClass('list').addClass('grid');
        }
        else if($(this).hasClass('list')) {
            $('#container ul').removeClass('grid').addClass('list');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Will try this in a few minutes. Thank you